# Can I install an MTK6577 ROM on a Star W007 6575 MTK?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, rom-flashing

I have a Star W007 single core MTK 6575. I downloaded a A8809 Jellybean for a MTK6577 dual core. Can you install this dual core rom on a single core. Most MTK stuff is interchangeable or are the drivers completely different?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't install a ROM on a different device than the one it was compiled for. Even devices based on the same SoC usually need differently configured ROM files, let alone ones based on different SoCs such as these two.